# In what cases do we have to use "hold true"?

Tags: grammar

***That analysis still holds true today.***

↑ I've seen that sentence from an article, and I have a question.
In my opinion, just saying "that analysis is still true today" can be also correct gramatically.

Can you tell me the difference between *hold true* and *be true*?

Answer (score 2):

The intransitive verb **hold** means to remain steadfast, to not weaken.

> Do you think that glued repair will hold?

To **hold true** means that the truth has not weakened with time. It is just as firmly true as it ever was.

To **be true** does not refer to the  passage of time in any way.

However, the adverb **still** does refer to the passage of time.

So, **it is still true** =  **it holds true**.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably most useful to think of *holds true* as a single phrase rather than considering *holds* as a modifier of *true*.

*Holds true* has the sense of *is applicable*. We take the an analysis of a past situation and find that it is applicable to the situation today, it holds true today.

Using *is true* doesn't work quite so well: it is not the correctness of the analysis itself that is interesting, it the use of the analysis in a different situation from that in which it was conceived. It is the combination of existing analysis and new situation we are considering. *Holds true* has this sense of applying something in a new context.

Answer (score 0):

That analysis is still true today.

That analysis still holds true today.

If something holds or holds true/good (less common in AmE),   that still exists or is still true, valid or applicable.

So if you remove the word "still" that sounds superfluous before hold in the second sentence , there's no difference in meaning between the two sentences presented.